# SPGridView SQL Server Data..Display

Tags: web-part

Any example code in C#.net with webparts, how to connect to SQL server and display a table data in SPGridView.

Answer (score 1):

IMO this is the best tutorial on SPGridView :

[Building A SPGridView Control – Part 1: Introducing the SPGridView](http://www.reversealchemy.net/2009/05/01/building-a-spgridview-control-part-1-introducing-the-spgridview/)

You can easily modify ObjectDataSource SelectData method to return data from SQL server.

Some additional info can be found in my answer provided on following question:

[Sharepoint 2007-Web Part - GridView -Paging Problem](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/19584/sharepoint-2007-web-part-gridview-paging-problem/19621#19621)

Answer (score 0):

find the below links,these might help
http://www.componentart.com/community/forums/t/64014.aspx
http://ctrlcvprogrammer.blogspot.in/2012/02/display-sql-server-data-in-gridview.html